# Is there a way to list the "last backup" file of a Database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, backup

I'm trying to do something really simple, but with one problem:

```
declare @cmd varchar(1000)

set @cmd='restore verifyonly from disk =''\\server\backup_folder\''?'''

exec sp_msforeachdb @cmd
```

Obviously its not working. I need the name of the backup file to run `Verifyonly` ( in the above code, i'm taking the Database name ).

Is there a way to automate `Verifyonly`, to run in all backup files?

How can I use the name of the *backup file* that has been made, in my code?

Thank you very much.

( People are saying `MsForeachdb` is not safe. I will try to search another option, like `Foreachdb` )

SQL SERVER 2008

EDIT1:  Well, As i see [here](http://marlonribunal.com/your-sql-server-database-just-failed-can-you-restore-the-backup/), I don't think `verifyonly` is a good idea, but will be good to know how to do it ( only for knowledge )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is just a matter of using dynamic SQL to process your data. You can also leverage `msdb.dbo.backupset` and `msdb.dbo.backupfamily` to find your most recent full backups.  This script will get the most recent full backup file location for each database and use it to run your cursor:

```
declare @dbname sysname
    ,@backupfile nvarchar(max)
    ,@sqlcmd nvarchar(max)

declare recscan cursor fast_forward 
for
select
    bs.database_name
    ,bm.physical_device_name
from
    msdb.dbo.backupset bs
    join msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily bm on (bs.media_set_id = bm.media_set_id)
    join (select database_name
            ,max(backup_finish_date) last_backup
          from msdb.dbo.backupset
          where type = 'D'
          group by database_name) lb on (bs.database_name = lb.database_name and bs.backup_finish_date = lb.last_backup)
where type = 'D'

open recscan
fetch next from recscan into @dbname,@backupfile

while @@fetch_status != -1
begin
    PRINT 'Validating '+@dbname
    select @sqlcmd = N'restore verifyonly from disk = '''+@backupfile+''';'

    exec sp_executesql @sqlcmd

    fetch next from recscan into @dbname,@backupfile
end

close recscan
deallocate recscan
```

Comment: You guys are really good. Hope I will be a DBA as good as you some day. Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that you can parameterize the path, so dynamic SQL isn't necessary.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, i can do this with **msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily** and **msdb.dbo.backupset**, right?

Comment: @Rafael Not sure I follow your question. This answer solves the problem, and yes you use those tables, I was only commenting on the code inside the cursor loop - it doesn't need to be dynamic, you can just say `RESTORE VERIFY ONLY FROM DISK = @backupfile;`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes, that answer solved my problem. I was just curious about your comment.  Thanks.